# If Condition in RewirteRule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am migrating an old website and as part of the task is the migration of the old URLs to the new format.

In the old format, we have lang2 that identifies ENglish, and in the new webpbage I see that the URL has changed to "en".
An old url looks like:

```
page/lang2/1111/some-title.html
```

I can extract the variables I need (pattern="page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html" from the above URL and handle a forward in a Rewrite Rule. What seems hard to do is alter the variable holding "lang2" into "en".
Any one has an idea how to do this?
The new URL should loook like /en/title.id and a full rule would have been:

```
ReWriteRule ^page\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*).html$ /$1/$3.$2  [L]
```

Problem is the $1 should be changed to "en" if lang2 and another code if "lang1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are only two options, "lang1" and "lang2"? Then simply make two separate rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?page/lang2/(\d+)/(.*)\.html$ /en/$2.$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?page/lang1/(\d+)/(.*)\.html$ /xx/$2.$1 [END]
```

Note: "xx" obviously is meant as a placeholder, you did not specify what you mean by "another code".

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I was always thinking in variables! Stupid of me not thinking in plain replacesers